# Big table names in doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have this "new" table in my database: `event_comment_oauth_service` which is an many-to-many relation table, between event_comment, and oauth_service.

I ran these commands to update my symfony2 entities:

`php app/console doctrine:mapping:import testSiteBundle yml`

`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities test --path=src/`

all tables are generated OK, but not the new one.

How can I generate the new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine2 does not act the same way as Doctrine1 for the many to many tables. If you want to have an entity, you have to create it and add one to many/many to one associations by yourself.

Comment: so this "relation" entity will never exist ?

Comment: If you just do a many to many using Doctrine default's m2m association, there won't be any entity. If you want an entity, you have to create yourself and set the correct relations.

Comment: thats ok for this case, but if i have an relation table with an "amount" column between "product" and "invoice" how i manage this ? the invoice table could have "N" amount of product. this doesnt work.

Comment: You'll have to create a ProductInvoice table which will be the relation table to Product and Invoices. You will be able to add as many columns as you want in ProductInvoice.

Comment: ok but symfony does not create entities for the many-to-many relation table "ProductInvoice". if i put an column "amount" there (in the database), it will not be created anywhere in the code after re-generating entities.